# How to convert a number (YYMMDDhhmmss) into timestamp in Oracle's SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion, numbers

I am trying to calculate a difference between `systimestamp` and a number in Oracle's SQL.

The number format is `YYMMDDhhmmss` (For example `190903210000`). This number is held in a table and is based on 24 hour timezone.

I am trying to calculate a difference that number and system timestamp in seconds.

I have to use a select sentence as below:

```
SELECT X FROM table
```

Then I need to calculate a difference `(SYSTEMTIMESTAMP - X)`

My system timestamp is formatted like `03-SEP-19 06.21.49.817757 PM +00:00`

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Comment: Did you try `to_timestamp()`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to add this curicial point. The x explained in my question is not a static value. I am taking this value in a table. It changes every single run. So, I could not use TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(...)) in a select statement. First of all, I need to have X from a table, then I need to convert and lastly having difference with timestamp. How can I convert a number to timestamp in a select statement?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `NUMBER` to a `TIMESTAMP` you can use an expression like `TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(...))`. To compute the number of seconds between two timestamps, one solution is to cast both to dates, and substract them : you will get a (decimal) result in days, which can be then converted to seconds.

Consider:

```
( 
    CAST(systimestamp AS DATE)
    - CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(190903210000), 'YYMMDDhh24miss') AS DATE)
) * 60 * 60 * 24
```

However, since your numeric representation of the timestamp does not contain fractional seconds (nor timezone), it would probably be simpler to convert directly to a `DATE`, which would remove the need to `CAST` it afterwards, hence:

```
(
    CAST(systimestamp AS DATE) 
    - TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(190903210000), 'YYMMDDhh24miss')
) * 60 * 60 * 24
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d4f2ed4734bde2633ec7bc7451855394)**:

```
SELECT 
    systimestamp,
    190903210000 num,
    TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(190903210000), 'YYMMDDhh24miss') num_as_timestamp,
    (
        CAST(systimestamp AS DATE) -
        CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(190903210000), 'YYMMDDhh24miss') AS DATE)
    ) * 60 * 60 * 24 diff
FROM DUAL;
```

```
SYSTIMESTAMP                        |          NUM | NUM_AS_TIMESTAMP                | DIFF
:---------------------------------- | -----------: | :------------------------------ | ---:
03-SEP-19 09.13.39.989343 PM +01:00 | 190903210000 | 03-SEP-19 09.00.00.000000000 PM |  819
```

```
SELECT 
    systimestamp,
    190903210000 num,
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(190903210000), 'YYMMDDhh24miss') num_as_date,
    (
        CAST(systimestamp AS DATE) 
        - TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(190903210000), 'YYMMDDhh24miss')
    ) * 60 * 60 * 24 diff
FROM DUAL;
```

```
SYSTIMESTAMP                        |          NUM | NUM_AS_DATE        |                                      DIFF
:---------------------------------- | -----------: | :----------------- | ----------------------------------------:
03-SEP-19 09.20.44.524445 PM +01:00 | 190903210000 | 03-SEP-19 21:00:00 | 1243.999999999999999999999999999999999996
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to add this curicial point. The x explained in my question is not a static value. I am taking this value in a table. It changes every single run. So, I could not use TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(...)) in a select statement. First of all, I need to have X from a table, then I need to convert and lastly having difference with timestamp. How can I convert a number to timestamp in a select statement?

Comment: @OnurSürmeli: no worries, this works equally well when taking the data from a table. Basically you just need to replace the word `DUAL` with your table name, and `190903210000` with the name of the column that contains the number. See [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=29432f415d7b6ffb4d92b8a1bff24de6) for your reference.

Comment: Hello, first off all thank you very much. It is working and I am using in my process. But I need a new query when the count of X from table is many. If the count of X is just one it is Ok but the count of x is not just one, Oracle says that ‘you can not subtraction many of X from just one value ( CAST(systimestamp AS DATE)). The thing described ‘one value’ is ‘systemtimestamp’ 
How can I progress?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 190903210000 n,
       to_timestamp(to_char(190903210000), 'YYMMDDHH24MISS') ts
from dual;
```

In [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/2220) and the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm).